# simple way to fetch data that are already in database with the help of php

Tags: php, mysql, database, php-5.3

A user log in first then a program form appears where he has to select the program_name. p_id is primary key and is auto incremented.The p_id and program_names are already stored in database.After submit the program form he will redirect to a page where some survey mapping with Program outcome is there.There will be some average calculation there and the average value will be stored in the survey tables.Now say in graduate_survey(id(pk) AI, PO1_avg, PO2_avg, p_id(fk), session) .
these are the field. Now i need that in the Foreign key field the pk of program table automatically enters. Actually, I would do it like this:

1. The user enters the program_name (I would do this as a drop down list and make available the programs present in the program table).
2. When the user picks the program_name I would immediately find the p_id of the program chosen by "SELECT p_id from program WHERE program_name=" and store it in some variable $p_id_picked or similar
3. Then the user gets re-directed to the survey,the user fills out the survey and hits submit. The submit triggers the "INSERT into graduate_survey(PO1_avg, PO2_avg, p_id, session) VALUES('2.5', '3.3', $p_id_picked, 'session info')"
   Only thing i need to do is keep track of the p_id of the program that the user picked in the first step,keep the p_id and use it when i insert the survey results.I just have to use a variable for p_id(fk).Codes are

Code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include("connection.php");
$program=$_POST['Program_name'];
$_SESSION['SProgram_name']=$program;
$Pname=$_SESSION['$Pname'];
if($_POST['submit'])
    {

        $sql="SELECT p_id from program WHERE Program_name='$program'";
        $rData=mysql_query($sql);
        $res=mysql_fetch_array($rData);
        if($res['Program_name']==$program)

            {   
                header("location:userhome.php?Program_name='$program'");
            }

    }

?>
<table width="68%" height="475" border="0" cellpadding="4" 
    cellspacing="4" align="center" bgcolor="#666666">
    <tr>
    <td height="467" colspan="2" align="center">
    <form method="POST">
    PROGRAM NAME<br><br>
    <select name="Program_name">
    <option>B.tech CSE</option>
    <option>B.tech IT</option>
    <option>B.tech EE</option>
    <option>B.tech AEI</option>
    <option>B.tech ECE</option>
    <option>B.tech ME</option>
    <option>B.tech CIVIL</option><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue">
    </form></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am unable to redirect to the survey page may be the `If` statement is wrong. Give me some ideas.
When the user picks the program_name It would immediately find the p_id of the program chosen by "SELECT p_id from program WHERE program_name=" and store it in some variable $p_id_picked or similar.I am unable to get this point.what value need to be stored in $p_id?

Comment: Within your SQL query, you don't retrieve `Program_Name` so it isn't there.  If you check your log file, you will probably see an invalid index error stating Program_Name could not be found in the array.

Comment: can you update the code? p_id and Program_names are already stored in database table...when one program is select from the drop down list it should find the p_id of the chosen program name. And if it matches it should redirect to some other page.